# Passing array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have this currently working:

```
sub first_sub
{
    my @my_array;

    ## The second sub will return my_array filled out!
    second_sub (\@my_array);

    ## Array ok ... filled out!
}
```

But what about if I want/need to pass the array from second_sub to another subroutine? For example:

```
sub first_sub
{
    my @my_array;

    ## The second sub will return my_array filled out!
    second_sub (\@my_array);
    ## ...
}

sub second_sub
{
    my $my_array = shift;

    ## The second sub will return my_array filled out!
    second_sub (my_array);   ## Passed by value ...

    ## Array empty here (because passed by value, right?) !!!
}
```

Comment: your script is broken, always copy working code, dont write it in form

Comment: Please make some sense out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have an *array reference* in a scalar variable you can pass it between subroutines as you wish.

Your example code is badly broken, but I assume you mean something like this

```
first_sub();

sub first_sub {
  my @my_array;

  ## second_sub will fill out @my_array

  second_sub (\@my_array);   ## passed by reference

  print join(', ', @my_array), "\n";
}

sub second_sub {
  my ($my_array) = @_;     ## received by reference

  ## third_sub will fill out @my_array

  third_sub ($my_array);   ## passed by reference
}

sub third_sub {
  my ($my_array) = @_;     ## received by reference

  @$my_array = qw/ a b c d e /;
}
```

**output**

```
a, b, c, d, e
```

Comment: sorry didn't update .. I fixed exactly in this way! 
btw, was exactly what I meant ....

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Please don't make trivial edits to posts. Adding a colon and changing the initial letter of comments to a capital letter is *no improvement whatsoever*

Answer (score 2):

You make a mistake by calling the subroutine

```
second_sub (my_array); # By the way, use miss there the $ or @`
```

You overgive it by reference, not by value. When there is a missing $.

If you want to overgive it by value then use:

```
second_sub (@{$my_array});
```

When you need the reference, treat it like a normal array:

#### Pass by reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub first_sub {

    my @numbers = (1..10);
    second_sub(\@numbers);
}

sub second_sub {
    my $array_ref = shift;
    foreach (@{$array_ref}) {

        # Treat it like a normal array here
        print $_;
    }
}

first_sub();
```

#### Pass by value:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub first_sub{

    my @numbers = (1..10);
    second_sub(@numbers);
}

sub second_sub {
    my @arrayParameter = @_;
    print "@arrayParameter\n";
}

first_sub();
```

Comment: second_sub(@numbers); does not pass ref

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sub first_sub {
    my @my_array;

    ## The second sub will return my_array filled out!
    second_sub (\@my_array);
    ## ...
}

sub second_sub {
    my $my_array = shift;

    ## The second sub will return my_array filled out!
    foreach my $newvar (@$my_array) {
        push (@new_array, $newvar);
    }   
}
```

This will populate the new array from the previous subroutine.